# Recursive tree view

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm new to clarity and want to construct a recursive tree view for the below data. How do i do it ?

parent= [
    {
        name: "xyz_center",
        selected: ClrSelectedState.INDETERMINATE,
        subfolders: [
            {
                name: "DS40G",
                selected: ClrSelectedState.INDETERMINATE,
                subfolders: [
                    {
                        name: "DS50F",
                        selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED,
                        subfolders: [
                          {
                              name: "DS50F1",
                              selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
                          }

```
                  ],
                    stores: [
                    {

                        name: "DS1",
                        selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
                    },
                    {
                        name: "DS61",
                        selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
                    },
                    {
                        name: "DS71",
                        selected: ClrSelectedState.SELECTED
                    },
                    {
                        name: "DS81",
                        selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
                    }

                  ]

                }
            ],
           stores: [
              {

                  name: "DS1",
                  selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
              },
              {
                  name: "DS61",
                  selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
              },
              {
                  name: "DS71",
                  selected: ClrSelectedState.SELECTED
              },
              {
                  name: "DS81",
                  selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
              }

            ]
        }
    ],
   stores: [
      {

          name: "DS1",
          selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
      },
      {
          name: "DS61",
          selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
      },
      {
          name: "DS71",
          selected: ClrSelectedState.SELECTED
      },
      {
          name: "DS81",
          selected: ClrSelectedState.UNSELECTED
      }

    ]
}
```

];

Comment: Clarity has starter stackblitz applications. Can you use one to demonstrate what you have already tried? https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

In addition to demonstrating what you have tried, can you let me know if there is something missing from the recursive tree documentation? https://v1.clarity.design/tree-view#recursive-tree

Comment: @hippeelee https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-dark-theme-v2-kkuxnv this the link of what i have tried